# Why is this linear equation system inconsistent?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the following linear equation system:
$$
(S)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
  a2008 + b = 34.564\\
  a2009 + b = 35.104\\
  a2010 + b = 35.481\\
  a2011 + b = 36.891\\
  a2012 + b = 37.331\\
  a2013 + b = 38.061\\
  a2016 + b = 39.071\\
  a2018 + b = 39.345
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and the corresponding augmented matrix
$$
\mathbf{M} =
\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 2008&1& 34.564\\ {}2009&1&
 35.104\\ {}2010&1& 35.481\\ {}2011&1&
 36.891\\ {}2012&1& 37.331\\ {}2013&1&
 38.061\\ {}2016&1& 39.071\\ {}2018&1&
 39.345\end {array} \right] 
$$
After bringing this to reduced row-echelonform it is evident that rank $\mathbf{M}$ > rank $\mathbf{A}$ and that the linear equation system therefore is inconsistent - note that $\mathbf{A}$ is the coefficient matrix.

However, bringing the augmented matrix to RREF takes time, and for some reason I was able to figure that it was consistent *before* performing any row operations. I think it is because that there are all  ones in the second column but it does not seem like a satisfactory argument/explanation.

So how would you argue that this linear equation system clearly has no solution (is inconsistent) without having the calculate anything?

Comment: That is no equation system, it is a matrix. Maybe write down the equation?

Comment: It is the augmented matrix of a linear equation system as I wrote?

Comment: But yea, I can also write the linear equation system in the question, even though it should not be necessary when you already have the augmented matrix for that system :))

Comment: Without any matrices or any fancy stuff, just look at the differences of the different rows in the first equation. On the left-hand side you always get $a$ (or a multiple of $a$), but what do you get on the right-hand side? Based on this, the right-hand side difference should always be the same ... Just take a look at the first three rows, for example.

Comment: In addition to what @MattiP. says: I generally don't use RREF reduction. You can use the fact that if there is a non-null minor $M$ of order $k$ and all minors of order $k+1$ obtained adding one row and one column to $M$ are null, then the rank of the matrix is precisely $k$.

Comment: @MattiP. can you please elaborate? It would be cool if you could elaborate with exapmles from my equation system in and post it as an answer :))

Comment: I think @gandalf61 has exactly the same idea as I had.

Comment: Oh, perfect! I did not really get what he meant but now with your text and his examples, I do. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you have only two independent variables $a$ and $b$, any two linear equations in $a$ and $b$ will have a unique solution (as long as they are independent). So you can pick two pairs of equations from your list, solve for $a$ and $b$, and see if the solutions are the same.

In this case it is particular easy to see that the equations in $S$ are not consistent:

$2008a + b = 34.564 \\ 2009a +  b = 35.104 \\ \Rightarrow a = 35.104 - 34.564 = 0.54$

$2009a + b = 35.104 \\ 2010a +  b = 35.481 \\ \Rightarrow a = 35.481 - 35.104 = 0.377$

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't take much effort to reduce $\mathbf M$.

$$
\left[ 
\begin {array}{ccc}
   2008 & 1 & 34.564 \\ 
   2009 & 1 & 35.104 \\ 
   2010 & 1 & 35.481 \\ 
   2011 & 1 & 36.891 \\
   2012 & 1 & 37.331 \\
   2013 & 1 & 38.061 \\
   2016 & 1 & 39.071 \\
   2018 & 1 & 39.345
\end {array} 
\right] 
$$

The result of 
\begin{align}
   2\mathbf M_2 &\to \mathbf M_2 \\
   \mathbf M_2 - \mathbf M_1 &\to \mathbf M_2 \\
   \mathbf M_2 - \mathbf M_3 &\to \mathbf M_2 \\
   \dfrac{1}{0.163} \mathbf M_2 &\to \mathbf M_2 \\
\end{align}

is

$$
\left[ 
\begin {array}{ccc}
   2008 & 1 & 34.564 \\ 
      0 & 0 &  1.000 \\ 
   2010 & 1 & 35.481 \\ 
   2011 & 1 & 36.891 \\
   2012 & 1 & 37.331 \\
   2013 & 1 & 38.061 \\
   2016 & 1 & 39.071 \\
   2018 & 1 & 39.345
\end {array} 
\right] 
$$

And we will quickly get

$$
\left[ 
\begin {array}{ccc}
   2008 & 1 & 0 \\ 
      0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
   2010 & 1 & 0 \\ 
   2011 & 1 & 0 \\
   2012 & 1 & 0 \\
   2013 & 1 & 0 \\
   2016 & 1 & 0 \\
   2018 & 1 & 0
\end {array} 
\right] 
$$

$$
\left[ 
\begin {array}{ccc}
   2008 & 1 & 0 \\ 
      0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
      2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
      3 & 0 & 0 \\
      4 & 0 & 0 \\
      5 & 0 & 0 \\
      8 & 0 & 0 \\
     10 & 0 & 0
\end {array} 
\right] 
$$

$$
\left[ 
\begin {array}{ccc}
   2008 & 1 & 0 \\ 
      0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
      1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
      0 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0
\end {array} 
\right] 
$$

$$
\left[ 
\begin {array}{ccc}
      1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
      0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
      0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
      0 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0
\end {array} 
\right] 
$$